# UIImageViews don't load in UIScrollView using imageNamed method

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Can someone tell me the difference between these two means of loading an `UIImageView`?

```
iconView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:anIconFileName];
```

and

```
iconView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:anIconFileName];
```

I ran into a situation where when using the `imageNamed` method I had non-deterministic behavior loading the UIImageViews as subviews on a `UIScrollView`.  The UIImages would load in the simulator, but not on a device using may iMac.  But when I moved to my Mac Air everything worked as expected in both the simulator and the device?  With further investigation, I found that it was nondeterministic when it worked.  I was trying to load 5 UIImageViews and sometimes I would get 1 or maybe two.  Getting any to load at all seemed to depend on the size of the *.png files I was trying to load.

When I changed with the `imageWithContentsOfFile` method everything worked as expected... reliably.

The UIImages didn't seem to be to large - about 100K each.  Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First thing - have you checked the name of image, because simulator load case insensitive image as well, while device will not load that.

`imageNamed` - this method takes file name.
`imageWithContentsOfFile` - this method take complete file path of that file name.

So above code which you have mentioned is dummy code or actual code, and if that is actual code then you need to be sure that with `imageNamed` you have to pass file name and with `imageWithContentsOfFile` you have to pass file path.

Check out this article for difference between these two method - 
http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2012/04/19/ios-imagenamed-vs-imagewithcontentsoffile/

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with the UIScrollView just check the way you imported the images to Xcode. You should add files selecting the option:

> Create groups for any added folders.

That way the folder will show in yellow (instead of blue) and imageNamed will work fine.

Comment: Thanks!  I deleted the files and re-added them (I normally use "Create groups for any added folders") and it worked with imageNamed.  Beats me how this is different and why it worked before on my Air but not on my iMac - but thanks for the suggestion.  Based on the article referenced in the previous posting I am going to profile and probably stick with imageWithContents.